# Modelling tree/hierarchy structure in Spring Data Neo4j 4.1

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

In order to model a tree/hierarchy (where the parent-child relationship can be traversed both ways) with Spring Data Neo4j 4.1, I wrote the following entity class

```
@NodeEntity(label = "node")
public class Node {

    @GraphId
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Long graphId;

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "PARENT", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Node parent;

    @Relationship(type = "PARENT", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Iterable<Node> children;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected Node() {
        // For SDN.
    }

    public Node(String name, Node parent) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

The problem is that, apparently, the presence of the `children` field screws up the `PARENT` relation such that there can be only one such *incoming* relation for a node. That is, as demonstrated by the following test case, a node cannot have more than one child - "conflicting" relations are automatically deleted:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = GraphDomainTestConfig.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE
)
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiredMembersInspection")
public class NodeTest {

    @Autowired
    private NodeRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Breakpoint 0

        Node A = new Node("A", null);

        A = repository.save(A);
        // Breakpoint 1

        Node B = new Node("B", A);
        Node C = new Node("C", A);

        B = repository.save(B);
        // Breakpoint 2

        C = repository.save(C);
        // Breakpoint 3

        A = repository.findByName("A");
        B = repository.findByName("B");
        C = repository.findByName("C");
        // Breakpoint 4

        assertNull(A.getParent()); // OK
        assertEquals(B.getParent().getName(), "A"); // FAILS (null pointer exception)! 
        assertEquals(C.getParent().getName(), "A"); // OK
    }
}
```

The test is set up to use the embedded driver. The log output at the "breakpoints" are as follows:

In order to keep the noise down, I've limited myself to include the log output that I think could be related to the problem. Please ask for more output in the comments if you need it. The same thing goes with configuration etc.

*Breakpoint 0*: Strange warning.

```
WARN: No identity field found for class of type: com.example.NodeTest when creating persistent property for field: private com.example.NodeRepository com.example.NodeTest.repository
```

*Breakpoint 1*: Node A is created.

```
INFO: Request: UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`node`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, row.type as type with params {rows=[{nodeRef=-1965998569, type=node, props={name=A}}]}
```

*Breakpoint 2*: Node B and its relationship to A is created.

```
INFO: Request: UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`node`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, row.type as type with params {rows=[{nodeRef=-1715570484, type=node, props={name=B}}]}
INFO: Request: UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) WHERE ID(startNode) = row.startNodeId MATCH (endNode) WHERE ID(endNode) = row.endNodeId MERGE (startNode)-[rel:`PARENT`]->(endNode) RETURN row.relRef as ref, ID(rel) as id, row.type as type with params {rows=[{startNodeId=1, relRef=-1978848273, type=rel, endNodeId=0}]}
```

*Breakpoint 3*: Node C and its relationship to A is created. But B's relationship to A is also deleted!

```
INFO: Request: UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`node`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, row.type as type with params {rows=[{nodeRef=-215596349, type=node, props={name=C}}]}
INFO: Request: UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) WHERE ID(startNode) = row.startNodeId MATCH (endNode) WHERE ID(endNode) = row.endNodeId MERGE (startNode)-[rel:`PARENT`]->(endNode) RETURN row.relRef as ref, ID(rel) as id, row.type as type with params {rows=[{startNodeId=2, relRef=-2003500348, type=rel, endNodeId=0}]}
INFO: Request: UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) WHERE ID(startNode) = row.startNodeId MATCH (endNode) WHERE ID(endNode) = row.endNodeId MATCH (startNode)-[rel:`PARENT`]->(endNode) DELETE rel with params {rows=[{startNodeId=1, endNodeId=0}]}
```

*Breakpoint 4*: Querying the repository.

```
INFO: Request: MATCH (n:`node`) WHERE n.`name` = { `name` } WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN p, ID(n) with params {name=A}
WARN: Cannot map iterable of class com.example.Node to instance of com.example.Node. More than one potential matching field found.
INFO: Request: MATCH (n:`node`) WHERE n.`name` = { `name` } WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN p, ID(n) with params {name=B}
INFO: Request: MATCH (n:`node`) WHERE n.`name` = { `name` } WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN p, ID(n) with params {name=C}
```

I suspect the problem to be connected to the warning in the second line (of "breakpoint 4"), but I don't understand the reason/solution for it.

Why can't the field be mapped? Why does this cause the semantics shown above? How do you correctly model a tree where you can traverse the parent-child relationship both ways?

*Additional information*:

If I remove the `children` field, the test passes. Reversing the direction of the relationship or making the field type (or subtype of) `Collection` doesn't make any difference.

The relevant project dependencies are `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile`, `org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-test:jar:2.0.4:test`, and `org.neo4j.test:neo4j-harness:jar:3.0.4:test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an incoming @Relationship, you must annotate the field, accessor and mutator methods with the @Relationship with type and direction INCOMING.

Secondly, I believe Iterable for children will not work with the OGM mapping process- implementations of List,Vector,Set,SortedSet will.

We have an example of a Tree here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/2.0/core/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/domain/tree/Entity.java and the test https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/2.0/core/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/persistence/examples/tree/TreeIntegrationTest.java

**Edit:**

So I've taken a look at the code again- Iterable will probably work. Might actually be a Set. Regarding your comment on parent.children.add(this), it is required because without it, your object model is not in sync with what you expect the graph model to be. When the OGM maps this, it could find that the child has a parent, but the parent does not include the child- and so it will pick one or the other as the source of truth.

Comment: Thanks, but the `children` field has no accessor nor mutator methods: The problem is caused by its mere presence. Adding (annotated) getter and setter methods and/or making the type of the field `List`, `Set` or whatever doesn't solve the problem. (Btw, it seems unnecessarily redundant to have to annotate everything - do you know why this should be necessary?)

Comment: In the `Entity` I see that `parent.children.add(this)` is called from `setParent`, which (at first glance) appear to solve the problem. I guess this makes sense now that the field is mutable. But I don't understand why it doesn't work to make the field `Iterable` - shouldn't this be valid according to ["... read-only fields are Iterable<T> ..."](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#__relationship_connecting_node_entities)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean that `Iterable` probably works. The whole question is about why it doesn't work, which the test proves that it doesn't. If the field is read-only, then there should be no conflict. What am I missing?

Comment: Your comment says " I see that parent.children.add(this) is called from setParent, which (at first glance) appear to solve the problem". So if that solves your issue, then it was not the Iterable. My answer points to a couple of areas that might contribute to your issue. Perhaps I have not understood what has fixed your issue or if it is still an issue

Comment: It's only possible to call `parent.children.add(this)` if `children` is modifiable (and I understand why it's necessary for the state to be consistent in that case). So yes, it appears to work if `children` is changed into a collection type. But I would like to understand why it can't be read-only, especially since the documentation that I linked to in my second comment says that it should work.

Comment: Right, so they're linked then. Because you have this bidirectional navigation which is required because you're navigating between entities of the same type, `children` must be modifiable to be able to represent the object graph correctly.

Comment: Ok I did not understand that the entities being the same type made a difference. Is this in the docs? And can you point to a resource that explains the reason for this?

Comment: If you think about it, you have a single Node class with two relationships of the same type to Node itself. An object model navigable in one direction only does not make sense if it's modelled with both parent and children, and hence, you must always set both the parent and children to be consistent. If you have entities related to other types, then it is possible to traverse in one direction only i.e. one entity will not have a reference to the other. Hope that helps.

Comment: Since the model is unambiguous, I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to work around these issues (or at least give better error messages). But is seems like an informed design decision and I accept your explanation, which would also make a nice improvement to the docs :) Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this is of some help- http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/09/03/sdn-4-object-model.html